# React Jest - import JS module without using require/export

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs, commonjs, separation-of-concerns

Is it possible to use Jest to test individual JavaScript files without using require/export?

Let's say I want to test abc.js. Here is an example of abc.js:

```
(function(){
   return {
       foo: function(){}
   }
})();
```

Now let's say my test file is abc.test.js. I want to test if foo is a function. How would I go on about testing this file without using modules.exports in abc.js and require in abc.test.js?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This doesn't look possible without transforming the underlying source file before Jest loads it. Is there a reason why you aren't using exports?

Comment: I don't want to include test code for my source files. I think I will have to use grunt or something to remove it for production

Answer (score 0):

Use a named function, a try/catch block, and an inline assertion to test it with plain Node.js:

```
const assert = require('assert');

(function hi(){
  hi.foo = Function;
  try
    {
    assert.ok(typeof hi.foo === 'function', 'Not a function');
    assert.ok(typeof hi.foo === 'string', 'Not a string');
    }
  catch(e)
    {
    console.log(e.message);
    }
  }
)();
```

then run it:

```
node foo.js
```

Comment out the test-oriented code to avoid including it in the source file:

```
/*const assert = require('assert');*/

(function hi(){
  hi.foo = Function;
  /*
  try
    {
    assert.ok(typeof hi.foo === 'function', 'Not a function');
    assert.ok(typeof hi.foo === 'string', 'Not a string');
    }
  catch(e)
    {
    console.log(e.message);
    }
  */
  }
)();
```

Then remove the comments programmatically and pipe the output to node in a *nix shell:

```
cat foo.js | tr -d '/*' | node
```

or Powershell:

```
$string = cat foo.js
$string.Split("/*") | node
```

And use Grunt or another tool to strip out comment blocks in the build process.

**References**

- [Errors | Node.js v8.1.3 Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html)
- [Assert | Node.js v8.1.3 Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html)
- [tr(1) Mac OS X Manual Page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tr.1.html)
- [grunt-stripcomments](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-stripcomments)
- [Using the Split Method in PowerShell – Hey, Scripting Guy! Blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/17/using-the-split-method-in-powershell/)
- [Extending JavaScript with inline unit tests](https://sergimansilla.com/blog/extending-js-inline-unit-tests/)
- [When I uncomment one line of code, I receive this error: _http_outgoing.js:359 throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41413776/1113772)
  https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-s2s-jest-unit-test-case
- [babel-plugin-s2s-jest-unit-test-case - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-s2s-jest-unit-test-case)